# Convert SQL into DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to convert the below SQL code to DAX , I am not able to get the same result as per SQL. Can we do this in single measure or do we need two measures and then subtract.

Also I am not able to use EXCEPT function in this case

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT( A.AccountNumber))   FROM factTable F
JOIN dimAccount A ON F.AccountKey = A.AccountKey and F.DateSk = A.DateSk
JOIN [dimDate] D on F.DateSk = D.DateSk 
WHERE D.IsLastDayOfMonth = 1 and D.DateKey > '2020-11-30' and D.DateKey <= '2021-11-30'
and ISNULL(F.Sale ,0) = 0   
and F.IsDeletetd = 0
and A.IsDeletetd = 0

and A.AccountNumber 
NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT(A.AccountNumber)   FROM fact F
JOIN dimAccount A ON F.AccountKey = A.AccountKey and F.DateSk = A.DateSk
JOIN [dimDate] D on F.DateSk = D.DateSk 
WHERE D.IsLastDayOfMonth = 1 and D.DateKey > '2020-11-30' and D.DateKey <= '2021-11-30'
and ISNULL(F.Sale ,0) > 0 
and F.IsDeleted = 0
and A.Deleted = 0
)
```

Comment: Where's your data? Please paste as copiable text with desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Going to assume your tables are as follows:

factTable
fact
DimAccount
DimDate

I am also going to assume that you have created relationships between Fact DimAccount and Fact and DimDate.

Your logic is that you want a count of all the Accounts in FactTable Table which do not exist in the Fact Table.

Not testing this so there are likely syntax errors, but the logic would have to be somewhat like the code below.  You may need to add in additional filters.  I think this will perform pretty poorly, but might give you what you nedd.

```
AccountCount = 
var excludetable = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            fact
            ,fact[IsDeleted] = 0 && RELATED(dimAccount[Deleted]) = 0 
             && Fact.Sale > 0
        )
        ,[AccountNumber]
        ,"DistinctAccounts",Max([AccountNumber])
    )
 RETURN 
    Calculate(
        DistinctCount('factTable'[AccountNumber])
       ,not( 'factTable'[AccountNumber] in (ExcludeTable[DistinctAccounts],1,0)
       ,factTable[IsDeleted]=0
       ,RELATED(dimAccount[Deleted]) = 0
       , Fact.Sale > 0)
    )
```

Comment: Check calculate syntax